# Shell out into zsh and execute commands from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vagrant, zsh

I'm trying my hand a little virtualisation, so I've been using vagrant to provision a centos7 vm and now I am configuring it with applications.

My vagrant config runs a bootstrap.sh file which is a bash script, in it I install zsh, then I want to configure it as per https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto .
step 1 is launch zsh then run some commands.

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
echo "Installing zsh"
yum install -y zsh

echo "Configure zsh"
# touch /home/vagrant/.zshrc
exec /usr/bin/zsh
git clone --recursive https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto.git "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto"
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
for rcfile in "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}"/.zprezto/runcoms/^README.md(.N); do
  ln -s "$rcfile" "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.${rcfile:t}"
done
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

I want this to be the default shell when I ssh into the VM. It does not appear to be working, there are no errors with the vagrant up step so I just want to know if this is possible and if this seems correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exec zsh` replaces your shell with zsh -- but doesn't in any way tell that instance of zsh to pick up at the same point in execution, or even to run the same script that the bash invocation was previously executing at all.

One easy fix is to feed the rest of your script to zsh via a heredoc:

```
/usr/bin/zsh <<'EOF'
git clone --recursive https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto.git "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto"
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
for rcfile in "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}"/.zprezto/runcoms/^README.md(.N); do
  ln -s "$rcfile" "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.${rcfile:t}"
done
chsh -s /bin/zsh
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you! Got it working with a bit of tweaking had to execute it as vagrant user as well. :D

Comment: `echo "Installing zsh"  
yum install -y zsh   
echo "Configure zsh"  
sudo -u vagrant zsh <<'EOF'  
git clone --recursive https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto.git "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto"  

setopt EXTENDED_GLOB  
for rcfile in "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}"/.zprezto/runcoms/^README.md(.N); do  
  ln -s "$rcfile" "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.${rcfile:t}"  
done  
EOF  

chsh -s /bin/zsh vagrant`

Answer (score 3):

`exec /usr/bin/zsh` replaces the running script with a new *zsh* process. Everything after that is not executed.

You have essentially two options:

1. Put the stuff specific to *zsh* into a separate script and run that with `/usr/bin/zsh`:

   vagrant:

   ```sh
   echo "Installing zsh"
   yum install -y zsh

   echo "Configure zsh"
   # touch /home/vagrant/.zshrc
   git clone --recursive https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto.git "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto"

   # run external script
   /usr/bin/zsh /home/vagrant/install-prezto.zsh

   chsh -s /bin/zsh
   ```

   `/home/vagrant/install-prezto.zsh`:

   ```sh
   setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
   for rcfile in "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}"/.zprezto/runcoms/^README.md(.N); do
     ln -s "$rcfile" "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.${rcfile:t}"
   done
   ```
2. Modify the script so that *zsh* is not needed for the installation:

   ```sh
   echo "Installing zsh"
   yum install -y zsh

   echo "Configure zsh"
   # touch /home/vagrant/.zshrc
   git clone --recursive https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto.git "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto"

   # use find instead of *zsh* to link files
   find "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto/runcoms/" -maxdepth 1 -type f -! -name README.md --exec ln -s {} "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/" +

   chsh -s /bin/zsh
   ```